# Return as a function: return()

Tags: python

Is it possible to make function with the name return that will simulate normal python return.

Why: So that in unittesting we can break from the method that have infinity loop:

```
while True:
    ...
    time.sleep(x)
```

I want to do something like this...

```
def return(y):
    ...

self.mock_module['time'].sleep.side_effect = [return(z)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is not possible. However, you can do something like this:

```
condition = []
while not condition:
    ...

self.mock_module['time'].sleep.side_effect = [lambda:condition.append(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have return as a function – because that function would simply return from itself. I think the solution you're looking for is an exception:

```
class StopTest(Exception):
    pass

def stopTest():
    raise StopTest()

...

    self.mock_module['time'].sleep.side_effect = [stopTest]
```

and then use `assertRaises` to expect the `StopTest` exception in your unit test.

Comment: Well, there's no accounting for taste. ;-)

Comment: Well nothing personal but but exception calling in side_effect is kinda dirty. :P. But yea you are right :D.